# what is the meaning of 腹んばいになって?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, readings, phrases, rendaku

What is the meaning of 腹んばい and 腹んばいになって？

Also, is it read 「はらんばい」？

I understand that 腹んばい悪い seems to mean 'get mad' (腹が立つ), but this other usage seems like it isn't about anger.

Here is the context from Akutagawa's Nyotai:

> 楊某
>   {ようぼう}
>   と云う支那人が、ある夏の夜、あまり蒸暑いのに眼がさめて、頬杖をつきながら腹んばいになって、とりとめのない妄想
>   {もうぞう}
>   に耽っていると、ふと一匹の
>   虱
>   {しらみ}
>   が寝床の
>   縁{ふち}
>   を這っているのに気がついた。

From googling, this word still seems to be in use.
I can't find this word in my kokugo dictionaries, which includes daijisen and genius (mac dictionary/goo).  Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[腹ん這い]{はらんばい}になって is an 音変化{おんへんか}  (shift in sound) of [[腹這い]{はらばい}になって](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%85%B9%E3%81%B0%E3%81%84%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6) "flat on one's belly".

In a similar way, [[四つん這い]{よつんばい}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%9B%9B%E3%81%A4%E3%82%93%E9%80%99%E3%81%84-654615) is an 音変化 of [[四つ這い]{よつばい}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%9B%9B%E3%81%A4%E9%80%99%E3%81%84-654578) for example.

See also [腹這い](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%85%B9%E9%80%99%E3%81%84-605066).

Comment: great, thanks, I was struggling with this.